# Need positioning of the image in ionic cordova android app

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to point out some places in a human body skeleton which I am having in my android app. I want those points to be triggered in some other place of the app. How can it possible? I am using ionic angular js for android app.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correct. you can use `ui-sref` and `ng-click` to body skeleton points.

> Using `ui-sref`:

you can simply link your `state` url `ui-sref="app.newpage"`

> Using `href`:

```
href="#/app/newpage"
```

state will be like :

```
.state('app.newpage', {
    url: '/newpage',
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/Pages/newpage.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

> Using `ng-click`:

```
  // your point of skeleton
    <div ng-click="gotopage();">

$scope.gotopage = function() {
  $state.go(app.newpage);
}
```

Comment: I want to give some points in the human image(patient module), those points can be stored in the database and can be triggered in some other place(another module called doctor module) with same points are placed. Any possibility?

Comment: hope it will help you but paid one http://www.humananatomyillustrations.com/human-anatomy-internal-external-illustration.html

Comment: and free http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html git link https://github.com/jamietre/imagemapster